# How do I output the most frequent letter used?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    x = {}
    for word in sentence: 
        x[word] = sentence.count(word)
    for letter in sorted(x):
        print (letter + ': ' + str(x[letter]))


sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
main()
```

this code outputs the letter and how many times it is used however how can i modify it to also find and print the letter used the most?

Comment: If you modify your code to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can take advantage of `Counter.most_common`

Comment: `import statistics` and `statistics.mode(sentence)`

Comment: i tried however im not too skilled with that function. any ideas?

Comment: This feels like such a bad dupe for OP. Even if the questions title are similar, doesn't mean they're duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an easy to read solution that is close to what you wanted to implement, that could do the trick,

```
def main():
    x = {}
    for word in sentence:
        if word != " ": 
            x[word] = sentence.count(word)
    maximum_occurrences = max(x.values())
    for letter,occurrences in x.items():
         if occurrences == maximum_occurrences:
              print("Max value found, the letter "+ letter + " was found " + str(occurrences)+ " times.")

sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
main()

>>>> Enter a sentence:  This is simply a test
>>>> Max value found, the letter s was found 4 times.
```

Basically it returns any letters with the most occurrences. Take note that this take care of the cases where more than one letter have the same number of occurrences.

**EDIT**

Also note that I added `if word != " ":` because your initial code would consider a space as a word which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the letters by values and then to write last member of that sorted array:

```
def main():
    x = {}
    for word in sentence:
        x[word] = sentence.count(word)

    sorted_letters = sorted(x, key=lambda v: x[v])
    for letter in sorted_letters:
        print (letter + ': ' + str(x[letter]))

    print('Most used letter =', sorted_letters[-1])


sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
main()
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter a sentence: Hello World!
H: 1
e: 1
 : 1
W: 1
r: 1
d: 1
!: 1
o: 2
l: 3
Most used letter = l
```

Comment: What if more than one letter have the same number of occurrences ?

Comment: @scharette That's edge case, op needs to specify it what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0):

So to find the maximum used word from the dict `x`, you could use `operator` like -

```
import operator
print max(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

But this will give you only one of n number of words having equal, i.e. max value

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you would want to use "defaultdict()" from collections
    What it does is even if you don't have the key in dictionary when calling it by keys,
    it won't cause any errors

```
import collections
s = "This is a random sequence of text"
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in s:
    if c != " ":
        d[c] += 1
print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0])
```